# Can't access encrypted home from other Ubuntu releases from 13.04

Tags: encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

Today I installed Raring Ringtail (again), 13.04 (production release), clean in a fresh partition on an AMD X2 64-bit system. I have a parallel installation of 12.10 and another one of 12.04 on other partitions. All $HOME dirs are encrypted. From 13.04 I cannot get to the other encrypted homedirs.

```
dman@nomotek-ur:/media/dman/nomotek-q/home/dman$ cat README.txt 
THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA.

From the graphical desktop, click on:
 "Access Your Private Data"

or

From the command line, run:
 ecryptfs-mount-private

dman@nomotek-ur:/media/dman/nomotek-q/home/dman$ sudo ecryptfs-mount-private 
Enter your login passphrase:
Inserted auth tok with sig [xxxx] into the user session keyring
fopen: No such file or directory
```

I did see that .ecryptfs and .Private are soft links and that they were set to a full path that is no longer valid from the currently booted OS. So I reset the links to relative paths pointing to the old filesystem. I still get the same error as to fopen.